# How do I make UITableViewCells same height on iPhone 6/6 plus?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, adaptive-design

My current app uses a UITableView, where I use the heightForRowAtIndexpath method to return the same height for every cell.

When I tried the Yo app, the height was the same on both a 4s and a 6 plus, just wider (obviously). However in my app, the rows got "taller" when I tried it on the 6 plus. How do I keep the heights the same. This also extends to other UI elements. All buttons etc, are all taller/wider despite being statically defined (in an amount of pixels as opposed to the percentage of the screen).

Comment: You have to add a LaunchImage.xib to tell iOS that your App is suited to run natively on an iPhone 6/6+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you don't support new iPhones sizes in xcode. You need to add new launch images for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6Plus. In xcode Image.xcassets, find you launch images. Select images for iOS 8, You should see image placeholders for Retina HD 5.5 and Retina HD 4.7. When you add those images your app will no longer scale to fit the screen on new iPhones.

(You may also use xib to render splash screen as dasdom suggested.)